# Before stopping the docker-container copy one file and store to the host

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a `docker-image`, which runs a python script. Basically, it is generating `.csv` file. I want to have the `.csv` file in my localhost machine before the `docker-container` dies out. Following is my `dockerfile`, can anyone please help me how to store the `.csv` file without running the `docker-container` again.

```
from ubuntu:18.04

run apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    python3 \
    git \
    python3-pip

run pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
run pip3 install opencv-python
run pip3 install keras
run pip3 install psutil
run pip3 install py-cpuinfo
run pip3 install https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/releases/download/2.0.3/imageai-2.0.3-py3-none-any.whl

workdir /data/code/



COPY . /data/
RUN ls /data/code/ | grep model

RUN chmod +x /data/code/image_prediction.py

CMD ["python3", "./image_prediction.py", "-OPTIONAL_FLAG"]
```

Comment: How to do you run your python script?

Comment: The last two lines of the `dockerfile` giving me the provision and helping to run my python script

Comment: I would just run this in a Python virtual environment, especially since you seem to have no OS-level library dependencies.  That would be easier, not require root-level access, and avoid this particular issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have your output sent directly to your host. You have to do it at the moment of running your docker image. Here is the step to do it:

1. Create a folder on your desktop for example and put your inputs data in it. Call it `input_dir`. The full path of this folder will have it like `/path/to/input_dir/` (you can get it by going inside this folder and type on terminal `pwd`).
2. Create another folder for the output of your script on your host machine in the desktop for example. Call it `output_dir`. The full path of this folder is: `path/to/output_dir`
3. Running your docker image should be like this:

   ```
    docker run -it -v /path/to/input_dir/:/data/ -v /path/to/output_dir/:/data/output/ my-image bash
   ```

Once done, your inputs will be automatically available in `/data/input` and make sure you set your output directory to '/data/output'

when you finish running your script, you will find your output on your host machine on the folder: `/path/to/output_dir/`

Comment: Dear, Just one thing when I run the following command - `docker run -it -v /home/souvik/input_folder/:/data/ /home/souvik/output_folder/:/data/output/  imageprediction bash`, I got the error - `docker: invalid reference format.`

Comment: Sorry I corrected it. I forgot one `-v ` between input and output directories. It should work now.

Comment: while the thanks words are very appreciated. We expresse this in StackOverflow with acceptance and upvote of the answer. I am glad this could work for you.

Comment: I already upvoted your comments but unfortunately... I don't have too many reputations so that my vote has not been counted for publicly display. :(

Comment: Good explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mount volume on your host, that will work.

If `.csv` is getting created at `/path/in/container` location inside the container then run

`docker run -itd -v /path/on/host/:/path/in/container <image>`

This should make your `.csv` available at `/path/on/host/` location on your host, even when your container dies.

Comment: After building my `docker-image`, I tried with the following command to run the docker-container - `docker run -itd -v /home/souvik/PycharmProjects/app_image_prediction/:/data/code/test.csv --name test imageprediction &` but it is giving me some strange error.

Comment: The error is following - `f02..
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:424: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/home/souvik/PycharmProjects/app_image_prediction\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var..2..28/merged\\\" at \\\"/var../overlay2/.../merged/data/code/test.csv\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type.`

Comment: Your `-v` option should be `-v /home/souvik/PycharmProjects/app_image_prediction/:/data/code/` don't put test.csv. the mounting should be between the directories not the exact file location.